# Adding Webp support to Revolution Slider

Tags: wordpress, webp

I want Revolution Slider to use webp images if there is any available but it has no support for webp. How can i make this work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open

> /wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/output.class.php

in a text editor.

1. Search for

   ```
    if($img_size !== 'full' && $cur_img_id !== false && !empty($cur_img_id)){
        $_urlImage = wp_get_attachment_image_src($cur_img_id, $img_size);
        $urlImage = ($_urlImage !== false) ? $_urlImage[0] : $urlImage;
    }
   ```

inside the function `get_html_layer()`. Add

```
    if ( !empty($urlImage) && !strstr( $urlImage, '.webp' ) )
        $urlImage .= '.webp';
```

below.

2. Search for

   ```
    $url = trim($this->remove_http($url));
   ```

inside the function `get_thumb_url()`. Add

```
    if ( !empty($url) && !strstr( $url, '.webp' ) )
        $url .= ($this->check_valid_image($url.'.webp')) ? '.webp' :  '';
```

below.

3. Search for

   ```
    $img['data-panzoom'] = $this->get_html_pan_zoom();
   ```

inside the function `get_image_data()`. Add

```
    if ( !empty($img['data-lazyload']) && !strstr( $img['data-lazyload'], '.webp' ) )
        $img['data-lazyload'] .= file_exists($img['data-lazyload'].'.webp') ? '.webp' :  '';
```

below. Next, open

> /wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/functions.class.php

in a text editor. Search for

```
    $img_exts = array('.gif', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png');
```

inside the function `check_valid_image($url)`. Then add `.webp` inside the array.

I'm assuming that you have webp images located in the same directory along with the non webp versions as this format:

```
background.jpeg
background.jpeg.webp
```